# Join two ids from one row with another table

Tags: mysql

I got two tables...

**fixtures**

[image]

and **teams**

[image]

Now I would like to display the names of both teams **(lteam and vteam)** playing against
each other in a table. I have tried to **LEFT JOIN** those tables, but that does not work. Guess you know why?

```
SELECT * FROM fixtures 

LEFT JOIN teams as a ON fixtures.lteam = teams.id
LEFT JOIN teams as b ON fixtures.vteam = teams.id

WHERE date_ko = '2017-05-19'
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What means *that does not work as I need*

Comment: change **fixtures.lteam = teams.id** to **fixtures.lteam = a.id** and **b.id**

Comment: with your sample data your query will never work. team.id=6 is not even in lteam or vteam. How do you think you can join the two tables?

Comment: yes, I know... I have no space for a screenshot with 8000 team rows. but the query works now. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The joins are not correct. Change this:

```
LEFT JOIN teams as a ON fixtures.lteam = teams.id
LEFT JOIN teams as b ON fixtures.vteam = teams.id
                                            |
```

To this:

```
LEFT JOIN teams as a ON fixtures.lteam = a.id
LEFT JOIN teams as b ON fixtures.vteam = b.id
                                         |
```

You need to use the alias in the join too

Comment: Cool! Thanks, but how can I use **a.id** and **b.id** now inside my `foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row)...`? `$row['a.id']` does not seem to work. Thanks for your support!